# how to marshall more than one pojo's in a single xml?

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-oxm

Is it possible to marshall all pojo (of same type) in a single xml using o/x mappers?
like I want to generate the following xml file

```
<xml>
<record1>
<id>1</id>
<name>abc</name>
</record1>
<record2>
<id>2</id>
<name>xyz</name>
</record2>
</xml>
```

here record1 and record 2 are same type of objects.Means I want to write first record1 object in xml file than record2 object in that same xml file.

Comment: What is a "single XML?" Consider editing your question to include an example of the desired input and output.

Comment: You could aggregate them into a parent class, and serialize that...

Comment: @Merlyn: Its a very valid answer. So... why not post it as an answer.

Comment: @Adeel: Because I program in C#, not Java, and don't want to embarrass myself ;)

Comment: @Merlyn: Fair enough, now upvote ;p

Answer (score 2):

As [Merlyn Morgan-Graham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/232593/merlyn-morgan-graham) said as a comment to your question, You can aggregate them into a separate class, and serialize that one.

Answer (score 0):

How about composition. A Pojo class contains other pojo's objects as xml entity.

Answer (score 0):

[Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/oxm.html) clearly says:

> Within the field of O/X mapping, a *marshaller* is responsible for serializing an object (graph) to XML.

So the direct answer is no. We marshal *one* object to *one* xml document. If you need more then one instance in a single document, you'll have to implement some sort of wrapper class. A class containing a simple collection (a list or a set) which stores your *marshallables* and providing some get/add methods should be sufficient.